# Tabela css tipo excel

Tags: html, css, tabela-html

Estou a criar uma tabela para inserção/consulta de dados que seja o mais parecido com o formato de uma folha excel.

**A minha tabela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Problema:**

Como a imagem acima mostra, ao colocar uma `input` num `td`, ela não ocupa a `td` toda, ficando com os seus rebordos, o que fica feio. O que pretendo é definir uma `class` `css` para a `input` de modo a que a mesma ocupasse toda a dimensão da `td` e parecendo que a `td` e a `input` fossem o mesmo elemento.

Comment: Você poderia tirar a borda do `<input>` e o padding da célula, mas ainda ficaria estranho. Por que não usa uma lib para isso?

Comment: Penso que não vale a pena importar uma lib para configurar células `td`

Comment: Ficaria mais organizado, dependendo do que for fazer. Se essa for a única tabela da aplicação, então ok.

Comment: Sim, em principio será a única. Nas restantes tabelas estou a usar DevExpress na aplicação, e queria replicar as GridViews o máximo possível. O problema é que nas GridView iria ter problemas em ter um campo para anexar ficheiros

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O que parece ser necessário, apesar de não teres a tua *markup* na tua pergunta, é formatar o input para remover algumas das suas definições de forma a que o mesmo passe a estar a ocupar toda a célula da tabela:

[**Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/46kjc/)

#### CSS

```
.myCellInput{
    display:block;     // ficar um elemento bloco
    width:100%;        // ocupar toda a largura
    margin:0;          // sem margens
    padding:0;         // sem padding
    border:0 none;     // sem borda
    line-height:20px;  // linha = altura pretendida para a célula
    height:20px;       // altura = altura pretendida para a célula
}
```

#### Resultado

[image: Captura de Tela]

**Notas:**
Podes ver no JSFiddle que também foram dadas algumas definições à tabela em si, pois não queremos que as `td` tenham espaço tipo `padding` para que o `input` possa ocupar todo o seu espaço.
Assim sendo, os links ou outros elementos deverão receber formatação adequada para compensar.

Comment: Era exactamente o que procurava! Obrigado ;)

Comment: Pena que não dá pra votar +2, pelo fato de usar line-height!

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa além da citada pelo Zuul, é usar a propriedade `contenteditable` no `td` que você deseja tornar editável, como pode acompanhar por este exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEGQ2/embedded/result/). Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Embora a do Zuul tenha sido a resposta mais completa, ao citar `contenteditable` a sua também é uma boa resposta

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem o que deseja porem te indico uma seguinte ferramenta Jquery:

https://datatables.net/

**Via Html:**

`<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/DataTables-1.7.6/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

**Carregar o css: Demo do plugin, você pode consegui-lo baixando a ultima versão deste plugin.**

`<link rel=’stylesheet’ href=’js/DataTables-1.7.6/css/demo_table_jui.css’ />

<link rel=’stylesheet’ href=’js/DataTables-1.7.6/css/demo_table.css’ />`

**Após carregar é necessário inicializar o script**

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $(‘#teste’).dataTable( ); 
        } ); 
</script>`

**Criar a tabela Física no Html**

`<table id="teste" width="100%"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Nome</th> 
                <th>Email</th> 
                <th>Sexo</th> 
                <th>Data Nascimento</th> 
                <th>Nivel Escolar</th> 
                <th>Faculdade</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            <?php for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ){?> 
            <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $i;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $i+1;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $i+2;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $i+3;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $i+4;?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $i+5;?></td> 
            </tr> 
            <?php }?> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>`